# Xcode: Creates a duplicated binary in .XCInstall after every build

Tags: xcode, macos

I am on the latest Xcode (14.2). I am building an iPad app to run natively on the M1 Mac using "Designed for iPad". Problem is that on each build, Xcode creates a brand new binary (MyApp, MyApp1, MyApp2,....MyApp300...). These binaries are in /DerivedData/MyApp-xxxxxxxxxxxx/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/.XCInstall/

Any way to stop that? Building for iPad or the simulator doesn't do that.

Answer (score 1):

Just add a build script like this:

```
rm -rf $TARGET_BUILD_DIR/.XCInstall/*
```

Answer (score 0):

I've been seeing the same thing, and it was chewing up my disk.

I created an empty new iOS project and saw the same thing; after the first run, each new Build & Run under "designed for iPad" created a new copy, in addition to updating the copy at the top level.

After more experimentation, I found that simply deleting the .XCInstall folder itself (as opposed to what I had been doing: deleting the files inside it) doesn't seem to create any problems, and build after build then occurs without the extra copy.  I tried the same thing in my main project and it seems to have fixed it.

YMMV!

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I tried but that did not work for me.

Comment: Yeah, mine came back after a while as well :(